# Virtual StringTree: How to determine if the node text is completely shown?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

When TVirtualStreeTree.HintMode = hmTooltip, the node text will become the hint text when the mouse is hovered over a node and column where the node text is not completely shown. But I have to set HintMode = hmHint, so that I can in the even handler supply various hint text based on the position the current mouse cursor is, and in that HintMode the hint text is not generated automatically. 
My question is how to know if the a node text is shown completely or not, so that I know should I supply the node text or empty string as the hint text? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `TBaseVirtualTree.GetDisplayRect` to determine the text bounds of a node. Depending on the `Unclipped` parameter, it will give you the full or actual text width. `TextOnly` should be set to `True`:

```
function IsTreeTextClipped(Tree: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex): Boolean;
var
  FullRect, ClippedRect: TRect;
begin
  FullRect := Tree.GetDisplayRect(Node, Column, True, True);
  ClippedRect := Tree.GetDisplayRect(Node, Column, True, False);
  Result := (ClippedRect.Right - ClippedRect.Left) < (FullRect.Right - FullRect.Left);
end;
```

Note that the function will implicitly initialize the node if it's not been initialized yet.

Comment: Thank you TOndrej, your code worked like a charm! I tried GetDisplayRect but I didn't notice we can accomplish this task by using this function alone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use what the tree control itself uses. Here's an excerpt from the `cm_HintShow` message handler for single-line nodes when `hmTooltip` mode is in effect.

```
NodeRect := GetDisplayRect(HitInfo.HitNode, HitInfo.HitColumn, True, True, True);
BottomRightCellContentMargin := DoGetCellContentMargin(HitInfo.HitNode, HitInfo.HitColumn
, ccmtBottomRightOnly);

ShowOwnHint := (HitInfo.HitColumn > InvalidColumn) and PtInRect(NodeRect, CursorPos) and
  (CursorPos.X <= ColRight) and (CursorPos.X >= ColLeft) and
  (
    // Show hint also if the node text is partially out of the client area.
    // "ColRight - 1", since the right column border is not part of this cell.
    ( (NodeRect.Right + BottomRightCellContentMargin.X) > Min(ColRight - 1, ClientWidth) ) or
    (NodeRect.Left < Max(ColLeft, 0)) or
    ( (NodeRect.Bottom + BottomRightCellContentMargin.Y) > ClientHeight ) or
    (NodeRect.Top < 0)
  );
```

If `ShowOwnHint` is true, then you should return the node's text as the hint text. Otherwise, leave the hint text blank.

The main obstacle with using that code is that `DoGetCellContentMargin` is protected, so you can't call it directly. You can either edit the source to make it public, or you can duplicate its functionality in your own function; if you aren't handling the `OnBeforeCellPaint` event, then it always returns (0, 0) anyway.

The `HitInfo` data comes from calling `GetHitTestInfoAt`.

Comment: Hi Rob, sorry, I didn't try this since TOndrej's code worked, thank you all the same!