# How to have both Tooltip and Hint hint modes?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

In Windows, if a column is too narrow to show full text, a `tooltip` appears inline and can show you the missing text:

[image]

It's important to note that hint window is **inline** with the text being displayed (i.e. it's not *"below"* the node).

This would be the equivalent of VirtualTreeview HintMode `hmToolTip`:

```
  TVTHintMode = (
    hmDefault,            // show the hint of the control
    hmHint,               // show node specific hint string returned by the application
    hmHintAndDefault,     // same as hmHint but show the control's hint if no node is concerned
    hmTooltip             // show the text of the node if it isn't already fully shown
  );
```

- **hmTooltip**: show the text of the node if it isn't already fully shown

### And also Hints; not just tooltips

Explorer also has the ability to show a **hint**, which is a hint windows that floats *near*, or *below* the cell being hovered:

[image]

This would be the equivalent in VirtualTreeview of `hmHint`:

- **hmHint**: show node specific hint string returned by the application

And you handle the **OnGetHint** event.

### Why not both?

Now comes the piece of resistance: Windows performing both functions, *at the same time*:

- showing you the full text (if it's cut off) *(ala `hmTooltip`)*
- as well as allowing me to add more text *(ala `hmHint`)*

[image]

But, if there is no additional text to show, it should continue to show just the inline tooltip:

[image]

And if it's not cut off at just: just the extra text:

[image]

I want that!

How can i do that?

### Research effort

- if i set **HintMode** to `hmTooltip`, then `OnGetHint` never fires (and i never get a chance to add custom information)
- if i set **HintMode** to `hmHint` (or `hmHintAndDefault`), then `OnGetHint` event fires, but the tree will no longer display the cut-off portion
- if the **HintMode** is `hmHint`, then the displayed hint will **never** be inline; but instead will **always** be below the cell

Is such a feature possible? At the very least i assume i'll have to re-invent all the cell measuring to figure out if the inplace text is cut off.

- but the the only way i can get an `OnGetHint` event
- is by setting **HintMode** to `hmHint`
- but if **HintMode** is `hmHint`
- then the hint will never be in-place
- but if i set **HintMode** to `hmTooltip` to make it in-place
- i'll never get the `OnGetHint` event
- `goto 10`

## Bonus Reading

- [Virtual StringTree: How to determine if the node text is completely shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099130/virtual-stringtree-how-to-determine-if-the-node-text-is-completely-shown)

## Edit: Clarification

I hate to do this, because it implies an answer or an avenue that could be pursued. But *imagine* the following truth table:

```
OnGetHint  IsTreeTextClipped  Hint
=========  =================  ==================
Empty      No                 No hint
Empty      Yes                Inline tooltip
Non-empty  No                 Hint below; shows only GetHint text only
Non-empty  Yes                Hint below; show both TreeText+CRLF+GetHint text
```

The problem is that you can never have an *inline tooltip* if `OnGetHint` is called.

- you can either your **OnGetHint** called (`hmHint`)
- or you can have an inline tooltip (`hmTooltip`)
- but you can never have **OnGetHint** called, and if it returns nothing, defer to `hmTooltip` mode

How can i have **OnGetHint** called with, and if it returns nothing, defer to `hmTooltip` mode?

Of course, nothing says that **OnGetHint** has to be involved at all. That was only an example of how get hint text to the VirtualTrees for processing.

Comment: I don't understnd - in your third pic the full text part isn't inline either. You can surely get this with VT by manually adding the full text in OnGetHint?

Comment: @UliGerhardt Added clarification section to the bottom of the question. Clear now?

Comment: Also added a mockup to let you contrast between the two hint window behaviors in the *same* treeview control

Comment: So the `OnGetHint` event should have an additional `var HintMode` parameter? :-)

Comment: @UliGerhardt That would be the ideal. Or ideally there would be a hint mode `hmHintAndTooltip`. Or, **ideally**, the tree would just call  `OnGetHint` when about to show an `hmTooltip`, and show the `hmTooltip` below, rather than inline. But those are all nice pie-in-the-sky ideas. How can i **actually** do it?